# django : TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django

I have the "TemplateDoesNotExist" error.
I already read severals answers about this problem, but it still does not work.
There is some part of my settings.py file :

```
import os


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

fews lines after :

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ["os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')"],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},]
```

and this

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
"/home/sarfraz/django/crepes_bretonnes/templates/", )
```

can somebody help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are putting the code that meant to be executed in a string. Replace:

```
'DIRS': ["os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')"],
```

with:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Comment: Oh my god, I just spent 2 hours of my life with a stupid syntax error. Thank you.

Comment: @winston_smith don't worry, we all do that. Sometimes just starting to write a question helps to spot a problem. Glad to help.

Comment: Yes, or you can explain your code to someone and you spot the problem ! Have a nice day